# Can't manage to render a chart with angular-chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I don't understand why my chart is not rendered. I followed rigorously the instructions from the [git-hub account](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) of `angular-chart.js`
Here is a plunker of my situation : http://plnkr.co/edit/x7XJhxxvYMzWr3u7lBcJ?p=preview

As you can see, I can read well different data related to that chart but I can't render the chart itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i removed the js files and added cdns for angular chartjs and Chart.js it works i guess there might be some problem with the ones u have included 
Use These

```
 <link data-require="angular-chart@0.8.8" data-semver="0.8.8" rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/dist/angular-chart.css" />
    <script data-require="chart.js@1.0.2" data-semver="1.0.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-chart@0.8.8" data-semver="0.8.8" src="https://rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that in your `angularchart.js` file you have minified source, which is pointing to source map `//# sourceMappingURL=angular-chart.min.js.map`

See more info about source maps [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Since that file is not available it was not working.

To fix your problem just paste not minified source. See forked [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/oOBYkkPhG6PWpkkxITKK?p=preview).